# Master Server with set of slave servers cooperation. Best practice

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, authorization, client-server

I have a task to build servers net with architecture like tree  using net core stack

1 master server
many slaves servers

**Conditions**

- Users works only with master
- Slaves are same configuration
- Master should authorize on  slave
- Master should send requests to slaves in two ways:

  ```
  1. To all in same time same request

  2. Only to one slave
  ```
- Slave should authorize on master
- Slave should send request to master
- Communications work periaodically, is not needed to have  continuous
  connection

Questions:

- What is the best practice to build communication between master and slaves?
- What is the best practice to do two-way authorization?

Comment: FYI we generally don't use master/slave terminology any more.

Comment: Thanks for comment. What terminology is correct?

Comment: It depends on the context. Primary/secondary, client/server, sender/receiver are all options.